# How to get user id from firebase in react native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I need your help I'm using firebase for my app. I'm trying to get the users ID not the logged users no all users I have. I want to show their (uid) simply like in an alert for each user. Also, I'm showing them in a flatlist and when I set `item.uid` in an alert it shows `(undefined)`. But, all the other data of the user is shown correctly. This what I did until now:

**
**users.js**
**

```
export default class usersList extends React.Component{

  state = {
    loading: false,
    uid: '',
    users: [],
    items: []
   };

   componentDidMount() {
        let itemsRef = f.database().ref('users').once('value').then(snapshot => {
               var data = snapshot.val();
               var items = Object.values(data);
               this.setState({items});
               console.log(snapshot.val())

            });
       }


  renderItem({item}) {
    return (
       <View key={index} style={{width: '100%', overflow:'hidden', marginBottom: 5, justifyContent:'space-between', borderBottomWidth:1, borderColor: 'grey'}}>
          <View>
          <View style={{padding:5, width:'100%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>

              <Text>{item.email}</Text>

          </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
  }

  render() {
   return (

     <View style={styles.container}>
     <ScrollView>
                {
                    this.state.items.length > 0
                    ? <ItemComponent items={this.state.items} navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                    : <Text>No stores</Text>
                }
                </ScrollView>
            </View>

  );
 }
 }
```

//ItemComponent.js

```
export default class ItemComponent extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
      items: PropTypes.array.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.itemsList}>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <View key={index}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={ () => alert(item.uid)}>
                    <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{item.email}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            )
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No when i runed console.snapshot.val(). i got this output >> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'console.snapshot.val')]
* app/Components/FamiliesList.js:31:32 in <unknown>
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules/promise/setimmediate/core.js:123:25 in <unknown>
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

Comment: if you don't get the correct data logged it means you are doing a wrong database call ````console.log(snapshot.val())```` -- run this

Comment: when i run console.log(snapshot.val()) i get the data correctly but when i run console.snapshot.val( ) i don't ,thanks i did not know that cuz i'm biggener, So,what do you advice me to do?? becuase eveything is depingind on that & i'm stuck,please anything could help?

Comment: in the method ````componentWillMount()```` when you run the ````console.log(snapshot.val())```` do you get all the IDs?

Comment: yes and this is and example of the log output  "tnUdqJkl0pcCuQLWGHBANV4l8XV2": Object {
    "age": "33",
    "avatar": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar",
    "email": "store4@store.com",
    "fName": "Store",
    "lName": "Store",
    "phoneNum": "1564237948",
    "storeName": "Store4 ",
  },
  "utZ60dru99ObFqrD042ZMBIlGN93": Object {
    "avatar": "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar",
    "email": "R@r.com",
    "name": "Enter name",
    "username": "@name",
  },

Comment: try setting the state as the following ````this.setState({items: items});````

Comment: unfortunately, nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

```
firebase.database().ref('user').on('value', (datasnapshot) => {
    this.setState({
       _id: datasnapshot.key
     });`
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me

```
<Text style={styles.yourStyleHere}>UID: {auth.currentUser?.uid} </Text>
```